# Android: When compatibility package is used, what version of SDK should I choose?

Tags: android

I remember Google says we should always use the latest API and set the min sdk to lower version.

My question is, If I use compatibility package, what Android SDK version should I use? If I use 4.0, will there be conflict? Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should still be targeting the latest SDK. Make sure that you use the compatibility package imports and not the SDK imports.